# UnboundLocalError: не удается получить доступ к локальной переменной 'batLeft', если она не связана со значением

Tags: python, tkinter

Купил ребенку книгу курсы для детей Pyton, при написании игры теннис возникла ошибка , что переменная 'batLeft' не привязана к значению, вот не знаю где мы ошиблись)) Помогите пожалуйста кто может)
Вот программа:

```
import tkinter
import time
canvasWidth=750
canvasHeight=500
window=tkinter.Tk()
canvas=tkinter.Canvas(window,width=canvasWidth,height=canvasHeight,bg="dodgerblue4")
canvas.pack()
bat=canvas.create_rectangle(0,0,40,10,fill="dark turquoise")
ball=canvas.create_oval(0,0,10,10,fill="deep pink")
windowOpen=True
def main_loop():
    while windowOpen==True:
        move_bat()
        move_ball()
        window.update()
        time.sleep(0.02)
        if windowOpen==True:
            check_game_over()
leftPressed=0
rightPressed=0
def on_key_press(event):
    global leftPressed,rightPressed
    if event.keysym=="Left":
        leftPressed=1
    elif event.keysym=="Right":
        rightPressed=1
def on_key_release(event):
    global leftPressed,rightPressed
    if event.keysym=="Left":
        leftPressed=0
    elif event.keysym=="Right":
        rightPressed=0
batSpeed=6
def move_bat():
    batMove=batSpeed*rightPressed-batSpeed*leftPressed
    (batLeft,batTop,batRight,batBottom)=canvas.coords(bat)
    if(batLeft>0 or batMove>0)and(batRight<canvasWidth or batMove<0):
        canvas.move(bat,batMove,0)
ballMoveX=4
ballMoveY=-4
setBatTop=canvasHeight-40
setBatBottom=canvasHeight-30
def move_ball():
    global ballMoveX,ballMoveY
    (ballLeft,ballTop,ballRight,ballBottom)=canvas.coords(ball)
    if ballMoveX>0 and ballRight>canvasWidth:
        ballMoveX= -ballMoveX
    if ballMoveX<0 and ballLeft<0:
        ballMoveX= -ballMoveX
    if ballMoveY<0 and ballTop<0:
        ballMoveY= -ballMoveY
    if ballMoveY>0 and ballBottom>setBatTop and ballBottom<setBatBottom:
        (batLeft,batTop,batRight,batBottom)=canvas.coords(bat)
    if ballRight>batLeft and ballLeft<batRight:
        ballMoveY= -ballMoveY
    canvas.move(ball,ballMoveX,ballMoveY)
def check_game_over():
    (ballLeft,ballTop,ballRight,ballBottom)=canvas.coords(ball)
    if ballTop>canvasHeight:
        playAgain=tkinter.messagebox.askyesno(message="Do you want to play again?")
        if playAgain==True:
            reset()
        else:
            close()
def close():
    global windowOpen
    windowOpen=False
    window.destroy()
def reset():
    global leftPressed,rightPressed
    global ballMoveX,ballMoveY
    leftPressed=0
    rightPressed=0
    ballMoveX=4
    ballMoveY=-4
    canvas.coords(bat,10,setBatTop,50,setBatBottom)
    canvas.coords(ball,20,setBatTop-10,30,setBatTop)
window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW",close)
window.bind("<KeyPress>", on_key_press)
window.bind("<KeyRelease>", on_key_release)
reset()
main_loop()
```

Вот такие ошибки :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\python\Lib\idlelib\18.py", line 82, in <module>
    main_loop()
  File "D:\python\Lib\idlelib\18.py", line 14, in main_loop
    move_ball()
  File "D:\python\Lib\idlelib\18.py", line 54, in move_ball
    if ballRight>batLeft and ballLeft<batRight:
UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'batLeft' where it is not associated with a value
```

Вроде все проверяли несколько раз , но так и не увидели ошибку((

Comment: batLeft, batRight у вас присутствуют только как локальные переменные внутри функций, внутри функции move_ball они не доступны. Попробуйте добавить строку `(batLeft,batTop,batRight,batBottom)=canvas.coords(bat)` выше строки, на которой показывает ошибку.

Comment: def move_ball():
    (batLeft,batTop,batRight,batBottom)=canvas.coords(bat). Вставив строку вначале все заработало. ошибки исчезли) Спасибо огромное))

Comment: Ну или почти все)) шарик вроде летает , но как то неадекватно, после проигрыша другая ошибка выскакивает : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\python\Lib\idlelib\18.py", line 83, in <module>
    main_loop()
  File "D:\python\Lib\idlelib\18.py", line 18, in main_loop
    check_game_over()
  File "D:\python\Lib\idlelib\18.py", line 61, in check_game_over
    playAgain=tkinter.messagebox.askyesno(message="Do you want to play again?")
AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'messagebox'

Comment: `AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'messagebox'` - нужно импортировать модуль messagebox, а не просто обращаться к нему как к атрибуту модуля tkinter.

Comment: Ну вообщем вставил вначале: import tkinter.messagebox, теперь все заработало корректно, ошибки больше не появляются.Получается в книге ошибка может быть. Спасибо за помощь!